# NSClassFromString() always returns nil

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, swift

The following code prints `nil`, despite `ListCell` is a valid class.

```
var lCellClass : AnyClass! = NSClassFromString("ListCell");

println(lCellClass);
```

The docs are saying that method returns

> The class object named by *aClassName*, or `nil` if no  class by that name is currently loaded. If *aClassName* is `nil`, returns `nil`.

I also tried to get `NSClassFromString()` of current viewcontroller which is LOADED but still get `nil`

What can be the problem ?

**Update:**
Even trying to do this `NSClassFromString("Array")` I still get `nil`

Comment: "Even trying to do this NSClassFromString("Array") I still get nil" Array<T> is a struct, not a class.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `NSClassFromString` function *does* work for (pure and Objective-C-derived) swift classes, but only if you use the fully qualified name.

For example, in a module called `MyApp` with a pure swift class called `Person`:

```
let personClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString("MyApp.Person")
```

The module name is defined by the "Product Module Name" (`PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME`) build setting, typically the same name as your target (with some normalization applied to e.g. remove spaces).

This is atypical, but if the class you're loading is in the current module and you don't know the module name at compile-time e.g. because the code is compiled as part of multiple targets, you can look up the bundle name dynamically, which *usually* corresponds to the module name:

```
let moduleName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
let personClass: AnyClass? = NSClassFromString(moduleName + "." + "Person")
```

I don't recommend this however unless you really don't know at compile-time.

See *Using Swift Class Names with Objective-C APIs* in [Using Swift With Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-XID_57) for more information.

Comment: And that's why I love SO!!

Comment: +1 Just curious is it documented anywhere like that?

Comment: Not currently, please file a bug report on the swift documentation at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: let navButtonClass = NSClassFromString("UINavigationButton")!
        if let topView = searchBar.subviews.first {
            for subView in topView.subviews {
                if subView is navButtonClass {
//                    subView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
//                    subView.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }

Trying to cast something as the return type of NSClassFromString does not work

Comment: In your example "MyApp" would be the target name, rather than the project name.
So the universal example for "MyCustomClass " would be something like:
`NSClassFromString(Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String + "." +  "MyCustomClass")`

Comment: Once your project name includes space, then it is necessary to replace the space with "_" in "Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String".

Comment: would anyone care to add a hlper to swift runtime so that we won't have to incorporate this fragileness into the app code???

Answer (score 23):

It's also possible to specify a name for the symbol in Objective-C which omits the namespace in objective C by using the @objc annotation.  If you prefer to use the name without the module, just use the same class name:

```
@objc(Foobar)
class Foobar{

}
```

NSClassFromString("Foobar") will return the class Foobar.

Comment: This is the most relevant answer, in fact. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't do this just to type a little less when using `NSClassFromString`. You lose all of the benefits of namespacing. You are *not* "defin[ing] the namespace of the swift class", you are *removing* all namespacing.

Comment: Does objective C support namespaces now?

Comment: No. It never did it never would. Once you add them you get swift and the fragile way to metaprogram using the JackLawrence's recipe.

Answer (score 0):

This may be problem that your class have not extend from NSObject. As by default swift does not have superclass.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

Just using UIViewController as an example,

```
func getVc(from stringName: String) -> UIViewController? {
    let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleName"] as! String
    guard let vc = NSClassFromString(appName + "." + stringName) as? UIViewController.Type else {
        return nil
    }
    return vc.init()
}
```

**If your App name contains "-" or number, just replace them with "_"**