# How to Initialize a class from a string in Swift

Tags: class, swift

I have an app I am making in Swift that references a bunch of different classes that are all very similar but slightly different. They all have the same methods and up until now I have been just been instantiating one of them for testing purposes. Now I need to be able to tell the view controller to instantiate and call the methods from a different class. I will not know which class to call until runtime.

`var studio = AudioStudio()`

Is how I am doing it now. But I want 'studio' to be able to be different versions of AudioStudio. I tried NSClassFromString but that doesn't work. I do want to call the class from the name in a string.

Comment: *" I tried NSClassFromString but that doesn't work."* – What exactly did you try? Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24570847/1187415?

Comment: I tried that and the compiler forces me to type cast it as "AnyClass" so it looks like this . "var studio: AnyClass! = NSClassFromString("AudioToy.AudioStudio")" but then all of the functions I call on "studio" suddenly say 'AnyClass' does not have a member named 'functionName'