# How to convert this code of NSClassFromString to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios7

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) alloc] init];
```

How to convert this code of `NSClassFromString` to `swift`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like this:

```
if let viewController = NSClassFromString(viewControllerName) as? UIViewController.Type {
   // Do something 
}
```

Comment: NSClassFromString does not work for Swift classes. In that case, you have to use full qualified name like `AppName.ClassName`. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570345/nsclassfromstring-always-returns-nil

Comment: @HoaParis yes, sure, however it works for classes inherited from NSObject (that's why for UIViewController this will work).

Comment: That code returns the class type, not the instance. You need to still call init() on the class type.